# Connect DS389 to W2012R2

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

Trying to configure DS389 to connect to a Windows ADDS server for a class practical.

I have been following [this guide](https://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php/709625-HowTO-Sync-Active-Directory-with-Directory-Server) because it's the only one I could find that explains what to do in plain English, but it's such an old post on a older version of DS389 that it doesn't work anymore.

I got stuck at the stage of trying to start a new windows sync agreement.

Has anyone else had experience with DS389 that could point me in the correct direction?

Edit:
Really Noob mistake.  I have worked out there was an add button off the screen I couldnt see because the vm window was so damn small....

Now i am stuck with trying to replicate the windows domain.  Its complaining about credentials but 100% sure the username and password i'm using are identical.

Comment: Hi there, Welcome to Superuser. Please let us know what Windows version you are using, any tools / software regarding the practical you are trying to do, any other important details that may help us. Also, try to put a screenshot / output of steps you are stuck at. This way you would get much better response.

Comment: there are screen shots in the guide where i got stuck at in the middle of step 6.  sorry for the delayed responce i havnt been in the prac room again till today.

Comment: Really Noob mistake.  i have worked out there was an add button off the screen i couldnt see because the vm window was so damn small....

Now i am stuck with trying to replicate the windwos domain.  its complaining about credentials but 100% sure hte username and passwords i'm using are identical.